# Is the Android JET file format proprietory, or is it open?

Tags: android

I need to programatically create a JET file from scratch for my Android project. Is the file format publicly available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that all of the JET/Sonivox files are in Android source (including lower level C files) it should be possible to work out the format.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/

Looking around, it appears that the manual is still on the main developer site but the tools (JetCreator) aren't in the SDK package anymore.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jet/jetcreator_manual.html

The JetPlayer APIs aren't marked as depreciated so they are still valid if seldom used. If you want to get the original tools you'll have to pull them from the AOSP:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/+/android-4.2.2_r1/jet_tools/

Realize they are dependent on a old version of Python (2.5.4) and wxPython (2.8.7.1). And there may be a native library required as mentioned in this thread when someone was looking for the Linux version:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/1bMxim9dikU

Since OpenSL ES 1.0.1 has been available from API 9 (2.3) in the NDK, developers now have more audio options than when JET was introduced in API 3 (1.5).

Comment: Thanks, that was informative. Are you aware of any Java bindings for OpenSL currently ?