# Where is the Android JETCreator for Linux?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I'm elaborating the possibilities of interactive sound playback on Android. After a little research, I stumbled across the [JetPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jetplayer.html) on the official developer pages. I liked the concept and wanted to give it a try. It says that a separate application called JETCreator is required for generating JetFiles.

About it's platform availability, it says:

> The tool is available on **Windows**, **OS X**, and **Linux** platforms (Linux does not support auditioning of imported assets like with the Windows and OS X versions).

Since I'm developing on Linux (Ubuntu), I was a little bit disappointed to have limited functionality. However, I would still really like to try it.

I followed the link to the [SONiVOX JETCreator User Manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jet/jetcreator_manual.html).
There it says:

> The JET Creator application is written in the Python programming language, therefore you need to have the current version of Python and WXWidgets installed. There is both a **Mac** and **Windows** version.

No mentioning of Linux?!

Another quote:

> The first is application is any off-the-shelf MIDI sequencing application that supports VST (for **PC**) or AU (for **Mac**) plugins. Here the author will compose their MIDI music files using the plugin as the synthesizer device. The second application is the JET Creator application.

Again no Linux reference (Ok one could argue, PC includes Linux and Windows)

It further states that you can start the JETCreator with the command:

```
python jetcreator.py
```

I infer from that statement, there must be a python file called **jetcreator.py** somewhere in the android sdk.

However, I couldn’t find any such file. I even tried to download as much as possible with Androids SDK Manager but had no luck.

Now I'm a little bit frustrated and would like to know if somebody knows what I'm missing? Where can I get the JETCreator for Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your questions are answered here: [Is the Android JET file format proprietory, or is it open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375496/is-the-android-jet-file-format-proprietory-or-is-it-open/15376544#15376544)

From what I recall the Jet Creator tool allowed for auditioning which wasn't built for the Linux side as implicated by the response here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/1bMxim9dikU

If you look at the JET Content Authoring Guidelines - the tools use a   'EAS Synth Virtual Instrument Plugin' which was only available for Mac and Windows.

Since everything is open source one could try to build Jet Creator for Linux but you are dealing with a tool set which was put into Android in the very early days (2009) and probably superseded by most developers with OpenSL ES or other parts of the Media stack or avoided due to existing known issues with Android, i.e. use your favorite search engine for 'Android audio latency' and which Google tried to address in Google IO sessions like this 2014 session on Media: https://youtu.be/92fgcUNCHic.

Comment: This sounds pretty disillusioning. I really liked the idea behind the JET Player. I'm still wondering why they write "The tool is available on Windows, OS X, and Linux platforms" on their page if there is no working Linux version available?!

Comment: My guess is that you can still edit and compile the JET file on Linux but actually verifying what you wrote would require a deploy to device rather than just listening to it on your Win PC/Mac.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your point. How would I 'edit and compile the JET file on Linux'? ....and what exactly should I 'deploy to device'?  Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: You would still need to extract out the JetCreator from the AOSP https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/+/android-5.1.1_r8/jet_tools/ and make it work on Linux. You just couldn't actually hear any MIDI since that needed the plugin. You could write an app to play the MIDI files and 'deploy to device' as one way to hear but really it isn't a workable solution.

Comment: Apologies - my suggestion for 'deploy to device' was a bad joke as it isn't really a workable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I got it. :) To sum up: It seems Google is basically lying on the "available on Linux" part.  Even if I could somehow make it work, it wont be a workable solution.  They should have mentioned that much more clear instead of wasting the time of developers searching for the JetCreator on Linux.