# Cant Find JetCreator in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use JetCreator to create sounds for my application and I can't figure out how the install it. As said in the JetCreator user's manual, I have installed Python (3.4) and wxPython. Unfortunately, I can't find any "jetCreator.py" file in the android sdk folder (the "jet" directory is not present in the "android-sdk/tools" folder).
Is JetCreator still available? Where can I find it? And where could I find an up-to-date user's manual?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15375496/295004

Answer (score 0):

Found this during my search...
jetCreator tool does not exist in the latest SDK -- Should be moved to extra. [37002989] - Visible to Public - Issue Tracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37002989